Zero vector for the subspace of real polynomials of degree greater than 4
I have encountered the following problem in my linear algebra I class:
Check if the set of real polynomials of degree greater than 4 is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]$
I was taught that to check whether a given set is a subspace, we first check if it contains the zero vector. Afterward, we can check the conditions of closed addition and scalar multiplication in one sweep by the following method:

Create two generic vectors of the set: $\mathbf{u} = (u_x, u_y, u_z)$ and $\mathbf{v} = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$.
"Modify" these vectors to make sure they satisfy the conditions of the set.
Form a vector $\mathbf{w}$, which is a linear combination of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, such that $\mathbf{w}=\left(\lambda u_x+\mu v_x, \lambda u_y+\mu v_y, \lambda u_z+\mu v_z\right)$, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are scalars.
Finally, check if $\mathbf{w}$ satisfies the condition of the set.
If this method shows that the condition is not fulfilled for all choices of $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then the set is not a subspace.

However, I’m a bit confused when it comes to checking whether the zero vector is part of the subspace when dealing with polynomials. Specifically, how does this apply to polynomials of degree greater than 4? The zero polynomial, by definition, has no degree, so I’m unsure how to verify if it belongs to the subspace.

Well, you could not worry about it and just note that $(2x^5+1)-2x^5=1$ has degree $0$ and not greater than $4$.  But yes, there's no valid interpretation of the degree of the zero polynomial that would put it in this subset.

$0$ is not in that set so it is not a subspace (vectorial)

You could add two polynomials of degree $>4$ (e.g., $x^5$ and $-x^5+x^2$) and get a result not in that set, so it’s not a subspace

@Piquito But how can you see/what is the proof? That it is not in it?

@MilesGloeklerSepe  There is nothing to prove. It's part of the definition of the degree of the zero polynomial (it is not greater than $4$).
